# Convergence of a Xn sequence that is given recursively

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

Lets say for every $X_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $X_n$ sequence. How can i prove that the sequence converges if the sequence is given recursively from the type of $X_{n+1} := \cos(X_n+{\pi\over 6})$, with $n\geq 0$ ?

Comment: Apply the Banach fixed-point theorem after restriction to a suitable interval.

Comment: The sequence is clearly bounded. Can you show that it is a Cauchy sequence?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2093236/recursive-sequence-convergence-with-trigonometric-terms?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this, (cos(x+π/6))' = -sin(x+π/6) , that means max| f ' | > 1 and thats not a contraction ( must be < 1) but we know that sinx is located in [-1,1] so max| f ' |  from -1 to 1 is equal with max(sin(x+π/6)) from 0 to 1 =  sin(1+π/6) < 1 it follows then that f is a contraction and according to Banach's theorem, it has a unique fixed point